# What is the difference: DRAM Throughput vs Global Memory Throughput

Tags: cuda, gpu, gpgpu, nvidia

The **actual throughput** achieved by a kernel is reported by CUDA profiler using four metrics:

- Global memory load throughput
- Global memory store throughput
- DRAM read throughput
- DRAM write throughput

*CUDA C Best Practices Guide* describes Global memory load/store throughput as the actual throughput and it says nothing specific about DRAM read/write throughput.

*CUPTI Users Guide* defines:

- Global memory load throughput as **((128*global_load_hit) + (l2_subp0_read_requests + l2_subp1_read_requests) * 32 - (l1_cached_local_ld_misses * 128))/(gputime)**
- Global memory store throughput as **(l2_subp0_write_requests + l2_subp1_write_requests) * 32 - (l1_cached_local_ld_misses * 128))/(gputime)**
- DRAM read throughput as **(fb_subp0_read + fb_subp1_read) * 32 / gputime**
- DRAM write throughput as **(fb_subp0_write     +    fb_subp1_write) * 32 / gputime**

I understand the DRAM read/write throughput since fb_subp* counters report a number of DRAM accesses (incremented by 1 for 32 byte access) and are collected for all SMs. So it is clear for me that throughput is calculated as function of gputime and number of bytes accessed.

I do not understand the Global memory throughput definition. There is no definition of the global_load_hit and  counter. I do not see why l1_cached_local_ld_misses is substracted in both cases.

**Is DRAM something different than Global memory in this context?**

**If I want to know what is the actual throughput of my kernel should I use the DRAM or the Global memory throughput metrics?**

Answer (score 2):

Global memory throughput is the amount of data requested by instructions from the global address space. global_load_hits is the number of L1 cache hits from global requests (cache line size is 128 bytes). The rest of the formula approximates the global throughput for accesses that miss the L1 by calculating all accesses to L2.

Global memory is a virtual memory space that can map to both device memory and system memory.

DRAM is the physical device memory (e.g. GDDR5 on the card). DRAM is accessed on L2 misses. The following virtual address spaces can be in DRAM/device memory (global, local, constant, instruction, and texture). Note that many of these memory spaces are virtual address spaces and the final data can reside in either DRAM or system memory.

Comment: There is **Requested Global Load/Store Throughput** metrics for the amount of requested bandwidth. The Global Load/Store Throughput reports actual throughput from global address space. Otherwise thank you for clarification of the difference between the Global memory (virtual address space) and DRAM memory.

Answer (score 0):

Global memory loads/stores go through caches; some of them may find a hit or a write-back. This would avoid access to DRAM. Therefore, global memory throughput depends upon the number of load/store requests and the hit/miss ratios of the caches.

In contrast, DRAM throughput is solely calculated based on the DRAM access, without considering any effect of caches.

To measure the kernel throughput in your case, you should use global memory throughputs, since those include the cache effects.

Comment: Should I use the DRAM throughput if I want to know how much of available bandwidth is utilized?